# "No local user being mapped error" when using unspecified NameId format" in OpenAM SAML2

Tags: saml-2.0, openam

We Use OpenAM version 13.0.0

and we faced the following error during using urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified

ERROR: spAssertionConsumer.jsp: SSO failed. com.sun.identity.saml2.common.SAML2Exception: No local user being mapped. at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.SPACSUtils.processResponse(SPACSUtils.java:1225) at org.apache.jsp.saml2.jsp.spAssertionConsumer_jsp._jspService(spAssertionConsumer_jsp.java:284) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)

Answer (score 0):

The hosted SP first uses the NameID map to extract the 'username' from the Subject (that holds the NameID) of the incoming SAML assertion and then use it to search the configured user data stores for an user identity subject (using the configured user search attribute). If this fails, it uses the configured account mapper to extract a 'username' attribute from the attribute statement. Here auto-federation configuration also matters.

--> It depends on the SAML response and OpenAM configuration why you run into this error. It's impossible to tell the root cause without seeing the SAML response and the OpenAM configuration. You may send it to me via (encrypted) email.

Comment: I understood from your question that to enable the unspecified NamId format.
We must store the user information in openAM DataStore.
Also, we must enable auto-federation configuration and modify openAM Authentication Settings (User Profile ) from required to Dynamic with user alias.

is this true?

I noticed that enabling the unspecified NameID is the same as enabling persistent federation.

But I looking for a way to support unspecified NamId format without persistent users in openAM datastore like the transient federation. @Bernhard Thalmayr

Comment: It's not that easy to explain everything in detail in a short post. In SAML there are basically two use-cases ... SSO and account linking. For both use-cases specific NameID formats are foreseen. For SSO this would be 'transient' NameID format. For account linking 'persistent' NameID format. 'Account linking' means that there are two identity silos, one on IdP side, one on SP side. 'auto federation' is a sort of 'account linking' where you populate the identity silo on SP side via SAML flow. So you actually first have to think about your use case.

Comment: Unfortunately not all SAML implementations support all NameID formats or do not handle them correctly, e.g. I have seen IdPs which sends an email address or a userid as value for the 'persistent' NameID .... this is not compliant with the SAML spec. 
If 'unspecified' NameID format is used, OpenAM tries to find a matching entry in its identity silo (OpenAM calls this user data stores) when 'User Profile' is set to 'required' because the AuthContext-based authentication (using the Federation auth module) is performed to generate an SSO session. It's similar to any other OpenAM authentication.